# Creating tibble returns error : "How to name Column 1 "

Tags: r

I'm attempting to create a single columned tibble where each row is single word from a vector but I'm unsure how to add a column name as the tibble has not been created.

This code :

```
as_tibble(strsplit("this is a test" , " "))
```

returns error :

```
Error: Column 1 must be named
```

How to name Column 1 ?

I attempted to add a name to result of

```
strsplit("this is a test" , " ")
```

but this is a string and so cannot be named ?

[[1]]
[1] "this" "is"   "a"    "test"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would transform the strsplit to a list, if you wanted a column name x:

```
as_tibble(list(x = (strsplit("this is a test" , " "))[[1]]))
# A tibble: 4 x 1
          x
      <chr>
    1  this
    2    is
    3     a
    4  test
```

Answer (score 1):

Isolate the first element of the list created:

```
as_tibble(strsplit("this is a test" , " ")[[1]])
```

Or name your list elements:

```
ls=strsplit("this is a test" , " ")
names(ls)="test_tibble"
as_tibble(ls)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just do:

```
> strsplit("this is a test" , " ") %>% as_tibble(validate=F)
# A tibble: 4 x 1
  ``   
  <chr>
1 this 
2 is   
3 a    
4 test
```

or you could do sth like:

```
> strsplit("this is a test" , " ") %>% map(as_tibble) %>% bind_rows
# A tibble: 4 x 1
  value
  <chr>
1 this 
2 is   
3 a    
4 test
```

This is useful because you sometimes need a default column name in order to do more complex list operations